# Reference Request: Johnson Filtration

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, reference-request

I need to learn the Johnson Filtration, which I believe is defined on the automorphism group of free groups. Can anyone recommend some reference to this topic? I know one paper called "On the automorphisms of free groups and free nilpotent groups" by S. Andreadakis, but I am not sure if it is the best or "standard" one to start with.

Comment: You can find some stuff on it in the Primer on Mapping Class Groups, by Benson Farb and Dan Margalit. But there isn't much - just a couple of pages (p198-199).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several papers by [Takao Satoh](https://www.math.kyoto-u.ac.jp/preprint/2010/04Satoh.pdf)  dealing with the Johnson filtration of ${\rm Aut}(F_n)$, which is a descending filtration
$$
{\rm Aut}(F_n)={\cal A}_n(0)\supseteq {\cal A}_n(1)\supseteq {\cal A}_n(2)\supseteq \cdots 
$$
with certain groups of automorphisms of $F_n$.
The Johnson filtration of ${\rm Aut}(F_n)$ was originally introduced in $1965$
by Andreadakis, which you know already. It is certainly a good starting point.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference!